# How to change one string to another with different sizes

Tags: arrays, c, char, c-strings, function-definition

I have a task to do. I have to work with strings. I will show you the input and output, because I think that will be clear what the task is.

Input: "aaa bbuvvvvo"

Output: "a$3 b$2uv$4o"

If there is the same symbols, I have to leave that symbol and then put dollar sign '$' and an integer of how many same signs was there. I am stuck on the spot, where I have to change string without losing any information.

I will leave my code here, it might help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CAPACITY 255
#define MAX_NUMBER 10

void Output(char readFile[], char outputFile[], char string[]);
void changeString(char string[], char newString[]);

int main() {

    char readFile[CAPACITY];
    char outputFile[CAPACITY];
    char string[CAPACITY];

    // Input file's name
    printf("Iveskite teksto failo varda: ");
    scanf("%s", &readFile);

    // Output file's name
    printf("Iveskite teksto faila i kuri bus isvedamas atsakymas: ");
    scanf("%s", &outputFile);


    Output(readFile, outputFile, string);
    return 0;
}

// Scanning file
void Output(char readFile[], char outputFile[], char string[])
{
    char newString[CAPACITY];
    FILE *input, *output;
    input = fopen(readFile, "r");

    while(fscanf(input, "%s", string) != EOF)
    {
        changeString(string, newString);
        printf("%s\n", newString);
    }
}

// Changing string to wanted string
void changeString(char string[], char newString[])
{
    char number[MAX_NUMBER];
    int symbols = 0;
    int j;

    for(int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        int temp = i;
        newString[i] = string[i];
        if(newString[i] == string[i + 1])
        {
            j = i;
            while(string[j] == string[i])
            {
                ++symbols;
                ++j;
            }
            // Changing int to char
            sprintf(number, "%d", symbols);
            newString[i + 1] = '$';
            i += 2;
            newString[i] = number[0];
            symbols = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to do that with function called **changeString**, but I get the wrong output all the time. Also the input I am getting is from .txt file.

**EDIT:**  When I compiling this program right now, I get **a$3 b$2v$4vo** that output.

Comment: In this record for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(string); ++i) sizeof( string ) is the same as sizeof( char * )

Comment: Amm, how I possibly can fix it? strlen() I think is the most efficient way?

Comment: Just use the condition string[i] != '\0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this declaration in main

```
char string[CAPACITY];
```

does not make sense.

You should declare variables in scopes where they are used.

The variable `string` is used in the function `Output` where it is should be declared.

The function `changeString` should be declared like

```
void changeString( const char string[], char newString[]);
```

because the source string is not changed within the function.

Your function has several bugs.

For example it does not build a string in the array `newString` because it does not append the stored sequence in the array with the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

Secondly this increasing of the variable `i`

```
i += 2;
```

in general is invalid. You need to add to the variable `i` the number of repeated characters in the source string.

Or the number of repeated characters change greater than or equal to 10. In this case this statement

```
newString[i] = number[0];
```

will not produce correct result.

The function can be defined the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CAPACITY 255

void changeString( const char string[], char newString[] )
{
    while ( *string )
    {
        *newString++ = *string;

        size_t n = 1;
        while (*++string == *( newString - 1 ) ) ++n;

        if (n != 1)
        {
            *newString++ = '$';
            int count = sprintf( newString, "%zu", n );
            newString += count;
        }
    }

    *newString = '\0';
}

int main( void )
{
    char string[CAPACITY] = "aaa bbuvvvvo";
    char newString[CAPACITY];

    changeString( string, newString );

    puts( newString );
}
```

The program output is

```
a$3 b$2uv$4o
```

Comment: Thank you, it really works. But I would liko to know how **while(*string)** works. Loop breaks, when '\0'?

Comment: @Kurbamit This condition while ( *string ) is equivalent to while ( *string != '\0' )

Comment: @Kurbamit If the problem is resolved then close the question selecting the best answer and your reputation will be increased.:)